# IDA - What LOC means in assembly?

Tags: ida, assembly

I have this piece of assembly:

```
.text:0041B322 xor     eax, eax
.text:0041B324 mov     al, byte ptr [ebp+v13]
.text:0041B327 cmp     eax, 1
.text:0041B32A jz      loc_41B37D
.text:0041B330 xor     eax, eax
.text:0041B332 mov     al, byte ptr [ebp+v13]
```

I would like to know what exactly is **loc_41B37D** in this context?
I believe this means **local piece of code**. So it would be a label pointing to some address in memory. But I coudn't find any definition for this online. Can you link me some useful resource for this? Documentation maybe?

Comment: loc = location it is the address where the jz jumps on condition true it is 0x56 bytes below the ip address of jz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"jz" is a conditional jump.
Explanation [HERE](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Control_Flow#Comparison_Instructions).

"loc" stands for location.

`jz      loc_41B37D` means if the zero flag was set to 1, jump to location 41B37D.

Reading [HERE](https://www.aldeid.com/wiki/X86-assembly/Instructions/jz) would also help.